# Issue in setting a particular datetime value to a JQuery UI datepicker with a time picker

Tags: php, jquery

i am using a form to add and edit users,
In that, one particular field is for adding datetime and i am using `jquery UI datepicker`([with a timepicker added](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)) and the problem is, since i am using the same form for adding and editing, when editing comes,fetched datetime value in the field changes  when i click on the field and the datepicker changes the value to todays date, can i set the **date and time** of the datepicker  to the value corresponds to the fetched value? i hope you understand the situation!

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, but it sounds like you just need to use datepicker's `setDate` method: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i set the default datetime format specified by the timepicker, it worked
Issue solved

Answer (score 0):

You can set the date in datepicker as follows

target.datepicker('setDate', "you date")

where target is the handle of datepicker field, the date set should be in the same format as configured for your date picker.